# Use ngSwitch instead of router-outlet because lack of support @Input in router-outlet directive

Tags: angular, router-outlet, ng-switch

I want to pass objects from a parent object to a child object, and I want to use router functionality. Because router-outlet has no support for @input I want to use ngSwitch. But I definitly need the router suport for protecting routes and so on and route activation in my Typescript child object.

I have created a stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4j2g7b?file=src%2Fapp%2Fadmin%2Fadmin.component.html

I have predefined a ngSwitch but I want to have the router functionality in the child objects(template) like  app-adminsub2.

This is my routing scheme:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'admin',
    component: AdminComponent, children: [
      {
        path: 'adminsub1',
        component: AdminSub1Component
      },
      {
        path: 'adminsub2',
        component: AdminSub2Component
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: 'user',
    component: UserComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'hello',
    component: HelloComponent,
  }
];
```

For giving you an overview.

This is the template code in the app-adminsub2 template and the Typescript code of this object.

```
<p>AdminSub2 works</p>

<h1>Suppliers</h1>
<p>The supplier for us is: {{ currentSupplier.description }} </p>
<p>Products:</p>
<ng-container *ngFor="let product of currentSupplier.products">
  <p>{{product}}</p>
</ng-container>

 @Input() currentSupplier : Supplier;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit () {

    console.log('Current supplier is: ' + this.currentSupplier.description)

  }
```

For other code see my Stackblitz with link above. Is it possible to add router functionality to a child object via ngSwitch or otherwise ?

Oh yes, important to mention, I need @Input and I can't use services.

Comment: why can't you use a service to communicate between components? That is a common way :)

Comment: our software architect doesn't want services.

Comment: Well, really should rethink that or then start with something else than angular. Services are a big part and that is also what angular docs recommend, to communicate via services. I don't know if it is possible to do what you want. At least in no easy way. Maybe someone smarter knows.

Comment: Your architect needs to be fired..

Comment: I will tell them. :-). Services are allowed off course but not in this particular case. The code I have showed here is just displaying the principles.

Comment: No answers ?  thats a pitty, Because the combination  at input  at output and ngOnChanges is a nice combination to use. Strange that Angular router-outlet doesn't support at input. Maybe it is because a router-outlet is a directive itself ? And a directive itself uses   at input to communicatie with external objects ?  I don't know its just a guess.